# What is the section for uninitialized global data?

Tags: gcc, elf

I am a little confused as to where uninitialized global variables go in the ELF file. I have this simple program to test in which sections the variables will be located:

```
const int a = 11;
int b = 10;
int c;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I know that uninitialized global variable should be put into .bss section of ELF file, but objdump -h gives me the following output:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000000a  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000004  00000000  00000000  00000040  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  00000044  2**2
                  ALLOC
  3 .rodata       00000004  00000000  00000000  00000044  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .comment      00000024  00000000  00000000  00000048  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  5 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  00000000  00000000  0000006c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

So the variable a goes to .rodata, b goes to .data, and c goes nowhere? When i change the code to:

```
int c = 0;
```

everything is as expected - .bss section has the length 4, but what happens with the variable c when it is not initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes into a "common section". You can see it with `objdump -t` or by using `nm`.

I'm not quite sure I understand what this is about, but the reference to the `ld` `-warn-common` flag says this:

```
int i;
```

> A common symbol.  If there are only
>   (one or more) common symbols for a
>   variable, it goes in the uninitialized
>   data area of the output file.  The
>   linker merges multiple common symbols
>   for the same  variable into a single
>   symbol.  If they are of different
>   sizes, it picks the largest size.  The
>   linker turns a common symbol into a
>   declaration, if there is a definition
>   of the same variable.

(Found via the `nm` man page.) There is more information after that in the man page itself.

Comment: I see... So the only way for a loader to know how much space it needs to reserve for "common" variables is to look at the symbols in the ELF file?